# How can I get all the properties from the class or id on click using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that how can I get all the properties from the class or id on click event

Means, suppose I have class and id:

```
.sample {
    margin: 10px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #4073ff;
}

#test {
    background: url(../sample.jpg) 20px 20px no-repeat cover red;  
}
```

now on click event I want all the

class properties print like this

```
<div id="cProperties">
  <h6>All properties from class comes here</h6>

  margin = 10px
  color = #000
  padding = 5px
  font-size = 60px
  border size = 1px 
  border style = solid
  border color = #4073ff

</div>
```

and id properties print like this

```
<div id="iProperties">
    <h6>All properties from id comes here</h6>

    background url = url(../sample.jpg)
    top = 20px 
    center = 20px
    repeteation = no-repeat 
    attachment = cover
    color = red  

 </div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/0d9utwjc/)

Comment: You want to get the properties from a web page, or the css file?

Comment: @wazz both web page and css file

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `.css` method to retrieve the properties.

Hope this snippet will be useful

```js
$(".sample").click(function() {
  var html = [],
    x = $(this).css([
      "margin", "padding", "color", "border"
    ]);

  $.each(x, function(prop, value) {
    html.push(prop + ": " + value);
  });

  $("#result").html(html.join("<br>"));


})
```

```css
.sample {
  margin: 10px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #4073ff;
}

#test {
  background: url(../sample.jpg) 20px 20px no-repeat cover red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<button class="sample">Click</button>
```

Comment: This should work - I've even been studying the MDN docs on it, but the only property value that's printing is color, even in js fiddle. Any idea why that would be? ... Just tried in chrome and it's fine. Also works in Opera. Seems to be a firefox (48) issue. Weird thing is, the samples on mdn work, just not here or fiddle. ... or Edge.

Comment: @brk wazz is right in firefox it is not working and also in safari for windows

Comment: @brk can you tell me that why your code is not getting value in Firefox ( 55.0b2 ) and Safari ( 5.1.7  ) for windows