# Why this code does not working properly on Firefox, Safari and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, safari

I have asked a question 2 days ago on Stack overflow. [How can I get all the properties from the class or id on click using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604616/how-can-i-get-all-the-properties-from-the-class-or-id-on-click-using-jquery)

I just want to know that why this code is not woking properly in Firefox, Safari and Edge and how can I fix it.

```
$(".sample").click(function() {
  var html = [],
    x = $(this).css([
      "margin", "padding", "color", "border"
    ]);

  $.each(x, function(prop, value) {
    html.push(prop + ": " + value);
  });

  $("#result").html(html.join("<br>"));


})
```

**About the code :**

The code is use to get the css properties of a element.

**Problem :**

As I described above and the problem is reported by the @wazz Thank you.

Please check the comment section in the given link.

Thank's in Advance.

**UPDATE :** Here is my full code

```js
$(".sample").click(function() {
  var html = [],
    x = $(this).css([
      "margin", "padding", "color", "border"
    ]);

  $.each(x, function(prop, value) {
    html.push(prop + ": " + value);
  });

  $("#result").html(html.join("<br>"));


})
```

```css
.sample {
  margin: 10px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #4073ff;
}

#test {
  background: url(../sample.jpg) 20px 20px no-repeat cover red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<button class="sample">Click</button>
```

Comment: What link are we supposed to check?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Sorry I forgot to provide the link. I have edited my question

Comment: Please provide HTML, there may be few reasons.

Comment: @llya Kantor Ya sure. Please wait a while.

Comment: @llyaKantor I have update my question

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById("elemId");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);
var keys = Object.keys(style); // will give margin,padding,color etc as keys  
var marginRight = style.margin-right;
```

This will give you an object of styles with keys as the name of the property. Works in Firefox like a charm

Comment: Sorry it does not wok.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, nothing to do with browser. Problem can be following I suppose:
1. $(".sample") selector may return more than one object.
2. Also check $(this) gives you exact DOM the one you want?

Comment: The problem on safari and firefox is margin, padding, border are empty except color

Comment: if it supposed to list as below, it is working for me:
margin: 10px
padding: 5px
color: rgb(0, 0, 0)
border: 1px solid rgb(64, 115, 255)

Comment: I am having problem in firefox (55.0b2) and safari ( 5.1.7  ) for Windows and I have got the problem but can't solve it the problem is it is not getting the values from each function and when I inspect element it shows NaN in firefox and Safari